# Get the elements of subsets in Balanced Partition using Backpointers

Tags: java, processing, partition-problem

I want to implement the Balanced Partition probelm and get the elements of the subsets using backpointers.

I have a question about Backpointers:

With the help of [MIT's Dynamic Programming Practice Problems](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/)  Nr. 7 and [this example code](https://sites.google.com/site/kevindrasingh/algorithms-r/balanced-partition-problem), I managed to get a working program in Processing (since I am a Programming novice...).

Now I want to be able to get the elements of both subsets.

In the MIT Video it is explained that this can be achieved "using the standard trick of maintaining backpointers".

Does anybody have an idea how this could be done?

```
int N=4;
int[] Weights=new int[N];
int Deviation=5;


void setup()
{
 for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
 Weights[i]=10+int(random(-Deviation, Deviation));
 println(i+"   "+Weights[i]);
} 

println("-------------------");

BalancedPartition(Weights,N);

}


void BalancedPartition ( int a[] , int n ){

    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        sum += a[i];

    int[] s = new int[sum+1];

    s[0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < sum+1 ; i++)    
    {
      s[i] = 0;
    }

    int ans = 0;
    int diff = 1000000000;


    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = sum ; j >= a[i] ; j--)
        {

            s[j] = s[j] | s[j-a[i]];
            if( s[j] == 1 )
            {   

                if( diff > abs( (sum/2) - j) )
                {

                    diff = abs( (sum/2) - j );
                    ans = j;


                 }

            }

        }
    }
println("Sum Set 1: "+ans+"        Sum Set 2: "+(sum-ans)+"          Difference: "+abs(ans-(sum-ans)) );



}
```